# Customize the Slider Swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

Made a slider "Swiper". To the right of it is the tag "h1", the text of which needs to be changed depending on what the current picture is.

1. If you press the right button, then the indexes are 2, 3, 4, and if the left one is 0, 1, 2.
   It is unclear why this is happening.
2. I tried to use the "document.getElementsByClassName("left-element")" class for searching, but it doesn't work that way.
   Works only with "document.getElementById("box")".
3. Also, at initial loading, the picture tries to be drawn at 100% in width, but then collapses to the 50% I need. How to remove this effect?

[image]

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        effect: 'cube',
        grabCursor: true, 
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        
        cubeEffect: {
           shadow: true,
           slideShadows: true,
           shadowOffset: 50,
           shadowScale: 0.3,
           centerSlidesBounds: true,
        },

        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: true,

        
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',

        },

 on: {
    init: function () {
     
    },
    },

        });

swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
  let name = swiper.activeIndex;
 /*
  let element = document.getElementsByClassName("left-element");
  alert(name);
 */
  let element = document.getElementById("box");
  element.innerHTML = (name) + " " + "Index";
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top:40px;
  width: 50%; 
}

.swiper-button-prev{
left:  2%;
}

.swiper-button-next{
left:  92%;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -25%;
}

.left-element {
    background: silver;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 0;
}

h1.left-element {
width: 80%;
height: 90%
}

 img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <h1 class="left-element" id="box">Empty index</h1>
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fonstola.ru/large/201309/119067.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
           <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fonstola.ru/large/201408/148243.jpg"></a> 
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fonstola.ru/large/201111/50599.jpg"></a>
        </div>
     </div>

        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried replace let `name = swiper.activeIndex` with `let name = swiper.realIndex`? I forgot how it's work but worth giving it a try I think. If I remember it correctly, activeIndex while having a loop will have some kind of duplicate indexes, that's why it's kind of messed up. So I remember that I used to use realIndex instead of activeIndex for these kinds of thing.

Comment: Yes, indexes are identified correctly, with "swiper.realIndex".
But, if you select with the left button, then the picture with the houses is selected twice (indexes 0 and 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed some of your effect on the Swiper, but feel free to add it back (cause I tried to set up the default Swiper again on the Swiper Docs :D ).

And remember to change the `<div class="swiper-container">` to `<div class="swiper">`

Here's the code in Javascript:

```
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  // Install modules,
  direction: 'horizontal',
  initialSlide: 0,
  loop: true,
  speed: 500,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  // ...
});



swiper.on('slideChange', () => {
let swiperIndex = swiper.realIndex
console.log('Swiper index right now: ', swiperIndex)
let element = document.getElementById("box")
element.innerHTML = (swiperIndex) + " " + "Index";
})
```

Whenever the slide change, it'll assign the `realIndex` to `swiperIndex`

Here's the `fiddle` for you to have a clearer look: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgbz4ny1/1/)

Comment: I tried to do this. If you pull the left edge to the right with the mouse, then where will the picture with the skyscrapers be, it will double.
I have updated the main message, where you can see the doubling in the screenshot.

Comment: I made a gif file where this effect is more clearly visible (replaced the picture with a gif)

Comment: I see, that's kind of weird.

Comment: Even if you press the left button: the picture with orange is not selected, but immediately scrolls through.

Comment: I think it's a bug or that's how the Swiper set up the `Cube` things at 4 angles, if you insert 1 more image into the Swiper to make it count into 4 pieces of a cube, everything will function correctly again. So I don't think we doing anything wrong here. Here's the fiddle that I've just tested.
Link: https://jsfiddle.net/bj09yrdk/16/
Due to the link in the document of Swiper, I have found the cube, it's set straight up 4 pieces of the image, no more or no less, so I think that's how it is set up.
Here is it: https://msfe6.csb.app/

Comment: Maybe it's a bug. With five pictures, there is a double image, but the index is displayed correctly.There is one more question why data by class is not selected (works only by id)?

Comment: As I said, I think it must be correctly `4 pictures`, no more or less for the cube to function correctly. I do not quite understand your question correctly, but if it's not selected, that means 1, you mistype the `getElementsByClassName`, sometimes we missed the `s` in `Element` or just remember to call `getElementsByClass`, not `ClassName`, don't worry, it's happening all the time :), and 2, you must make sure that element is class (you should check it in the DevTools) so that it'll work.

Comment: 1. let element = document.getElementsByClass("left-element"); does not work 2. let element = document.getElementsByClassName("left-element"); does not work 3. let element = document.getElementById("box");  Works.

Comment: Remember to use it like this `let element = document.getElementsByClassName(left-element)[0]`, because when you are using `Elements` not `Element` like ID, it'll returns an HtmlCollection, an array-like structure containing the DOM elements that matched your query

Comment: Thanks! It worked.